# How to change the appearance of empty folders in finder?

Tags: macos, osx-lion, icons, finder

I'm looking for a way to change the appearance of empty folders within finder in order to distinguish them from folders with contents.

Does anyone know of a way to do this, either through third party software, through the OS, or programmatically?

Comment: The only way I could think of would be to go through all directories with a shell script, then [coloring the folders](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2435580/tagging-files-with-colors-in-os-x-finder-from-shell-scripts) depending on whether they're empty or not. This, however, won't work automatically, you'd have to trigger it.

Comment: That could work - I'd just need the part of the script that identifies empty folders I guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This simple script goes through all empty folders starting from, for example, `~/Desktop`, and applying the color `7`, for grey.

Change these values to your liking, e.g. the folder to `~/Documents` to go through all your files in the Documents folder. The label colors start at `0` for *none*, and `7` is the highest number.

```
#!/bin/bash
label=7
start=~/Desktop
while IFS= read -d '' -r dir; do
    osascript -e "tell application \"Finder\" to set label index of alias POSIX file \"$dir\" to $label" > /dev/null
    echo "Applied label to $dir"
done < <(find $start -mindepth 1 -type d -empty -print0)
```

---

To run this script, open a terminal through *Applications/Utilities/Terminal.app*, and open a text editor like `nano`.

Paste the contents, and save it by entering <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>O</kbd>, then typing a name for the file. Press <kbd>↩</kbd> when done. Now make it executable with `chmod +x recolor.sh`, and run it by typing its name like `~/Documents/recolor.sh`.

It will print the path of all folders it applied the label to, and exit once done. Note that this will *not* automatically identify any new empty folders you might create in the future, so you'll have to run this script again.

[image]

One could also replace the call to `osascript` with the `label()` function from [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5252057/435093).

Answer (score 2):

The following solution is mostly bash (shell) scripting, but integrated with *Automator* to make it more convenient to use.

Open Automator and select to create a new *Workflow*. Add a *Run Shell Script* action, that receives input *to stdin* and the following script:

```
find "$@" -type d -empty
```

If you run that in Automator, all empty folders will be shown in the *Results*. To act on them, add e.g. a *Move Finder Items To Trash* action or a *Label Finder Items* action below that.

By making this an Automator workflow, you can repeatedly execute it conveniently, or even make it executable as a *Service* on selected files or folders (*File » Convert To… » Service*, or start by making it a Service). That way, if you want to clean up a specific folder and its contents, you can do that quite easily.

You can assign keyboard shortcuts in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts » Services*.

[image]

Comment: Me thinks I've made the shell script a bit too complicated...

Comment: Haha, I was gonna say :P – but using Automator is probably nicer. Feel free to "steal" the shell script.

Comment: Is there a way to make this task constantly run? Or  maybe run it once a day?